# how can i list input devices using jack in C

Tags: c, jack

I'm trying to write an audio application in C.
for now I support pulseaudio and alsa, now it's time to support jack.

I want to be able to retrieve input devices in jack in order to choose one, connect to it and record the audio from that device.

what I didn't manage to understand is how to get the list of record and playback devices available in jack.

any ideas regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the [Looking up ports](http://jackaudio.org/files/docs/html/group__PortSearching.html) section of the manual has the function

```
const char ** jack_get_ports(jack_client_t *, const char *port_name_pattern,
                             const char *type_name_pattern, unsigned long flags);
```

If you call it with `NULL` patterns and set flags to `JackPortIsInput`, I would expect it to list available input ports.

Comment: by your answer i was able to find the following sample code: http://trac.jackaudio.org/browser/trunk/jack/example-clients/simple_client.c thanks!